# How to encodeToBase64String a Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer (Video) in WinJS

Tags: video, encoding, winjs

I have an app which takes a picture with the web camera then get the bytes and then I use a method for converting it on base64, everything works okay

then I wanted to add video and do the same with it (get bytes and convert them to base 64) but it doesn't work, this is the code:

```
        var f = Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromPathAsync(capturedItem.path);

        return f.then(function (file) { return file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.read); }).then
            (function (stream) {
                var inputStream = stream.getInputStreamAt(0);
                var size        = stream.size;
                var reader      = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(inputStream);
                return reader.loadAsync(size).then(function () {
                    var b = reader.readBuffer(size);

                    //Creates the array, datalist and the namespace for making this data public                    
                    ImageData.dataArray[ImageData.dataArray.length] = { title: capturedItem.name, id: "img" + ImageData.dataArray.length, picture: photoBlobUrl };
                    ImageData.arrayCaptures.push(capturedItem); //Stores the data into array (full captured object)
                    ImageData.arrayTextFieldValues.push(Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.encodeToBase64String(b)); //Stores captured converted into bytes

                    updateCaptureList(ImageData.dataArray); //updates the grid with all the screenshots
                });
            });
```

Then I wanted to print a log for observing bytes:

```
console.log("variable: " + b.toString() + "lenght: " + b.length);
```

result on both cases (pictures and video)

```
variable: [object Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer]
lenght: 2087358
```

but when I want to see the Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer converted I console.log this

```
console.log("data: " + ImageData.arrayTextFieldValues[ImageData.arrayTextFieldValues.length - 1]);
```

just on pictures I get a result like this:

```
data: /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAAAAAAAD/4QCCRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAYdpAAQAAAABAAAAGgAAAAAABJADAAIAAAAUAAAAUJAEAAIAAAAUAAAAZJKRAAIAAAADODAAAJKSAAIAAAADODAAAAAAAAAyMDE0OjAyOjI2IDE5OjUyOjE5ADIwMTQ6MDI6MjYgMTk6NTI6MTkAAAD/4QGgaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNv.....
```

but with video I can't even get the log printed, I think the method that is failing is:

```
Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.encodeToBase64String()
```

I want to find a method for encoding my videofile to base64, any help I'll appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Too late but, I share What i notice in your Snippet :

**You have to replace** :

```
console.log("variable: " + b.toString + "lenght: " + b.length);
```

**To** :

```
console.log("variable: " + b.toString() + "lenght: " + b.length );
```

`b.toString()` is a method and you have to use Parenthesis after that. Because here you `call` that `method` ,If you pass this `method` then the whole `function` is in your `variable` Because you just Pass it like `b.toString`.

*That's why your variable contains* :

```
variable: 
function toString() {
[native code]
}
```

May it helps you .

Comment: thanks but now I get variable: [object Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer] lenght: 1793623 but still not getting the bytes converted to string base64 :(

Comment: when you get your stream then apply `Filereader.readAsDataURL(inputStream)`, check how to use `FileReader();` by using this you may able to convert your stream to base64.